# Update the settings and retry if ajax fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my current code , which is calling api and will do something

```
function callApiAjax(url,token){
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": url,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "token": token,
        }
    };
    var callAPI = $.ajax(settings);
    callAPI.done(function(){
        doSomethingWhenSuccess();
    });

    callAPI.fail(function(){
        doSomethingWhenFail();
    });

}
```

It works but sometimes the token will be expired. I have another api that can update the token. So I want to add another api into the fail function.
Could I do something like that?

```
function callApiAjax(token,retry) {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": url,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "token": token,
        }
    };
    var callAPI = $.ajax(settings);
    callAPI.done(function () {
        doSomethingWhenSuccess();
    });

    callAPI.fail(function () {
        if(retry){
            var updateTokenSetting = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": url,
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "token": token,
                }
            };
            var updateToken = $.ajax(updateTokenSetting);
            updateToken.done(function (response) {
                //Set the original settings.headers.token to response.data.token;
                //Redo the "CallAPI" ajax Call Once

            });
            updateToken.fail(function () {
                doSomethingWhenFail();
            });
        }else{
            doSomethingWhenFail();
        }

    });

}
```

I don't want to copy the settings in the fail function because I think that would be too complex and difficult to read but I don't know how to update only the token and redo the ajax call *only* one time.

Have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: So recall the method that is making the call with the new setting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
updateToken.done(function(response){
    callApiAjax(response.data.token, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant anything you have to call token api into fail function. But you can reorganize your code statments like this.

```
function callApiAjax(token,retry) {
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": url,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "token": token,
    }
};
var callAPI = $.ajax(settings);
callAPI.done(function () {
    doSomethingWhenSuccess();
});

callAPI.fail(function () {
    if(retry){
        var updateToken = $.ajax(settings);
        updateToken.done(function (response) {
            //Set the original settings.headers.token to response.data.token;
            //Redo the "CallAPI" ajax Call Once

        });
        updateToken.fail(function () {
            doSomethingWhenFail();
        });
    }else{
        doSomethingWhenFail();
    }

});

}
```